# How do i make try / catch work on full list

Tags: c#

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {

        class Table
        {
            public int NubmerOfChairs { get; set; }
            public List<object> ListOfGuests { get; set; }

            public Table(int ChairNum)
            {
                this.NubmerOfChairs = ChairNum;
                this.ListOfGuests = new List<object>(ChairNum);
            }
        }

        class Gost {

            public string name;
            public string secname;
            public string gender;
            public string status;
            public  string bd;
            public  string gmail;

            public Gost(string name, string secname, string gender, string status, string bd, string gmail)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.secname = secname;
                this.gender = gender;
                this.status = status;
                this.bd = bd;
                this.gmail = gmail;        
            }
        
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //MizaPolnaException, ki se proži ob poskusu dodajanja gosta na že zapolnjeno mizo.
            Table polnaMiza = new Table(2);
            try
            {
                Gost novGost = new Gost("Jack1", "black1", "M", "student", "22.2.1966", "testxxx@gmail.com");
                Gost novGost2 = new Gost("Jack2", "black2", "M", "student", "22.2.1966", "testxxx@gmail.com");
                Gost novGost3 = new Gost("Jack3", "black3", "M", "student", "22.2.1966", "testxxx@gmail.com");

                polnaMiza.ListOfGuests.Add(novGost);
                polnaMiza.ListOfGuests.Add(novGost2);
                polnaMiza.ListOfGuests.Add(novGost3);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new TableFull("No chairs left");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to throw an error when I add a third guest because my list is only 2 elements long can someone please help me I am new to c#. I added my list length by ChairNum I've read on stack overflow by putting in int you set the max value of list

Comment: Rather than adding directly to the list, add a `.Add` method to your Table class that checks how many chairs there before adding the guest.

Comment: Yeah but i need to use try catch i am a student and its a part of a class but thank

Comment: As @Loocid says, create an `Add` method in the `Table` class that throws an exception if the maximum number of guests is exceeded. This will then be caught by the `try/catch`.

Comment: You can still use try catch as you've done. Inside the Add method you can throw an exception if there are too many people at the table, which your try catch will be able to handle.

Comment: `because my list is only 2 elements long` The key bit to understand in your faulty reasoning is that the list is _not really_ 2 long. It has an _initial capacity_ of 2 but it will grow and shrink as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce an `Add` method to Table and use that for throwing exceptions if the number of adds is more than the number allowed.

```
class Table
{
    public int NubmerOfChairs { get; set; }
    public List<Gost> ListOfGuests { get; set; }

    public Table(int ChairNum)
    {
        NubmerOfChairs = ChairNum;
        ListOfGuests = new List<Gost>(ChairNum);
    }

    public void Add(Gost guest)
    {
        if (ListOfGuests.Count == NubmerOfChairs)
            throw new ApplicationException("Not enough Chairs");
        ListOfGuests.Add(guest);
    }
}
```

and use this in your main,

```cs
Table polnaMiza = new Table(2);
try
{
    Gost novGost = new Gost("Jack1", "black1", "M", "student", "22.2.1966", "testxxx@gmail.com");
    Gost novGost2 = new Gost("Jack2", "black2", "M", "student", "22.2.1966", "testxxx@gmail.com");
    Gost novGost3 = new Gost("Jack3", "black3", "M", "student", "22.2.1966", "testxxx@gmail.com");

    // Instead of directly adding novGost to List, use the Table method
    polnaMiza.Add(novGost); 
    polnaMiza.Add(novGost2);
    polnaMiza.Add(novGost3);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("No chairs left");
}
```

Note: You dont have to use the try/catch in this instance because the Add method will throw an exception anyway. there is no reason to throw another exception within catch. Its unnecessary unless you do something else besides throwing the same exception.

Comment: Updated the post. I would recommend using strongly typed classes as well, like the one you already have, `Gost`.

Comment: Consider making the list a field, and have the property be of type `IReadOnlyList` to dissuade people "coming in the back door".